# Is it possible to simulate with some composition of signals an analog of a function of two variables and then to calculate its gradient?

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, signal-processing

With the help of an operational amplifier (op amp), a signal can be differentiated, using it in a differentiator mode. Due to that we can calculate an analog of a derivative of a mathematical function that is implemented in form of an electric signal. If necessary, we can submit the result to the ADC to represent it in the digital form. It's interested is it possible

1. to generate with some composition of signals an analog of a function of two variables $$ x = u \sin 2v; $$
2. then with help of op amps (or something else) to calculate the gradient of this function that is $$ \nabla x = \sin 2v \mathbf{\hat{i}} +  2u \cos 2v \mathbf{\hat{j}} ?$$

Comment: Why not use a circuit simulator and prove this for yourself?

Comment: @Andyaka It is a good idea! What would the thing be to get started?

Comment: Try LTSpice,  it's free to download and pretty quick to get something up and running, my first instinct is that getting a good precision in real life may potentially be difficult

Comment: @Entropy Thanks! But what is if after implementation of the idea to calibrate the real working circuit to increase the accuracy? Can it help?

Comment: I'd use micro-cap (again free) and, as easy to use as LTspice.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks! What software would you recommend for this purpose for Linux OS?

Comment: Read my previous comment